# Connected to multiple hubs and disconnect from only one

Tags: signalr

I'm writing a Single Page Application with Durandal and I'm planning on using SignalR for some functionality. First of all, I have a top bar that listens for notifications that the server may send. The site start a connection to the "TopBarNotificationHub".

On one of the pages I want to connection to another hub as two users might edit the data on this page simultaneous and I want to notify if someone updated the data. No problem, this works fine.

But, when leaving that page I want to disconnect from ONLY the second hub, but I can't find a way to accomplish this. If I just say hub.connection.stop(); the connection to th eTopBarNotificationHub also stops (as it's shared).

Is there a way to just leave one hubproxy and let the other exist?

As this is a SPA the "shell" is never reloaded so it doesn't connect to the hub again... I might be able to force this to reconnect everytime another page disconnects from a hub, but there might be a cleaner solution...

Thanks in advance.

//J

Comment: What's your server language? It's not in your tags (makes examples easier in the answers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use multiple hubs on a single page that's fine, but they share the same connection, so it isn't taking up more resources on the client other than receiving the updates.

Therefore to "connect and disconnect to/from a hub" you need to slightly rearchitect. If you use Groups instead of Clients on the server side you can "register" with a Hub by calling a (for example) `Hub1.Register` method and sticking the client in the relevant group in that method. To "deregister" you call a (for example) `Hub1.DeRegister` and remove the client's `ConnectionId` from the group in that method. Then, when you push updates to clients, you can just use the Group instead of `Clients.All`.

(C# assumed for server language as you didn't specify in your tag)

- To add a client to the hub group: `Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupNameForHub);`
- To remove a client from the hub group: `Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, id.ToString());`
- To broadcast to that Hub's clients: `Clients.Group(groupNameForHub).clientMethodName(param1, param2);`

Just to make it confusing, though, note that the group named "myGroup" in Hub1 is separate to the group named "myGroup" in Hub2.

This is the exact approach recommended [in the documents](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-server) (copied here in case they move/change in later versions):

> Multiple Hubs
>
> You can define multiple Hub classes in an application. When you do that, the connection is shared but groups are separate:
>
> • All clients will use the same URL to establish a SignalR connection with your service ("/signalr" or your custom URL if you specified one), and that connection is used for all Hubs defined by the service.
>
> There is no performance difference for multiple Hubs compared to defining all Hub functionality in a single class.
>
> • All Hubs get the same HTTP request  information.
>
> Since all Hubs share the same connection, the only HTTP request information that the server gets is what comes in the original HTTP request that establishes the SignalR connection. If you use the connection request to pass information from the client to the server by specifying a query string, you can't provide different query strings to different Hubs. All Hubs will receive the same information.
>
> • The generated JavaScript proxies file will contain proxies for all Hubs in one file.
>
> For information about JavaScript proxies, see [SignalR Hubs API Guide - JavaScript Client - The generated proxy and what it does for you](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#genproxy).
>
> • Groups are defined within Hubs.
>
> In SignalR you can define named groups to broadcast to subsets of connected clients. Groups are maintained separately for each Hub. For example, a group named "Administrators" would include one set of clients for your ContosoChatHub class, and the same group name would refer to a different set of clients for your StockTickerHub class.

Comment: Thanks! I hade missed the concept of "Groups" and did see a Hub as a Group instead of Groups that are defined inside of a Hub. Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Would you recommend multiple groups in a single HUB or multiple Hubs each with single group?